# Operating System Property Values (2k8 R2 vs Win7)

Tags: windows-installer

I'm looking at the Microsoft article for [Operating System Property Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370556(VS.85).aspx) and it seems that both Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 have a `VersionNT` value of `601`. I see in the comments on the article that you should use [`MsiNTProductType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370329(VS.85).aspx) to differentiate the two.

So if I wanted to only allow server 2008 R2 installations (and not Windows 7), then would this be the correct condition:

```
MsiNTProductType > 1 AND VersionNT = 601
```

This would allow me any Windows 2008 R2 PC that is a domain controller or a server (Which Windows 7 is not?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just built a MSI installer with that launch condition and that will indeed work just fine.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I would have tried it myself, but I do not have a 2k7 OS setup ATM.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent failing in the future you should use:

```
MsiNTProductType > 1 AND VersionNT >= 601
```

This means your condition will still install on yet-to-be-developed versions of Windows Server. Note that `>=` is required if you are putting your software forward for logo testing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I generally do not allow the more generic version, as you never know what functionality new version may deprecate.